# The constant STEP_PAUSE in Calabash 0.5.5 throws an error

Tags: android, calabash, calabash-android

I am trying to add the line `sleep(STEP_PAUSE)` to my android calabash script and I am getting the following error

```
 uninitialized constant STEP_PAUSE (NameError)
```

Why is this not initialized and does anyone have the class list of constants, operators and methods that can be used in Calabash Android 0.5.5?

Here is the class list I found, but the search sucks and I can't find what i need: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/calabash-android/Calabash/Android

Wondering if STEP_PAUSE was deprecated?

Here's what I'm trying to do. I am trying to wait for the app to launch and then open a side menu. Here is what I am using but its not always successful. Its like 90% effective

```
#open the menu
Then(/^I touch "(.*?)" menu$/)do |menu|
sleep(STEP_PAUSE)
wait_for_elements_exist(["* id:'action_bar_title'", "* text:'New courses'"], :timeout => 35.0)
touch("* id:'action_bar_title'")
end
```

Also note the timeout options for 35 seconds doesn't seem to ALWAYS work, but helped stabilize the script. Again only 90% of the time does it actually wait and work. This is why I am trying the SLEEP_PAUSE. SLEEP_PAUSE fixed a lot of things for me in iOS.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if STEP_PAUSE has been removed from Calabash, because using sleeps is strongly not recommended. Have you tried to add `:retry_frequency` and `:post_timeout` to your wait block/method instead?

Comment: The :retry_frequency seems to be working 100% of the time.